# Public URLs have web/ prefix while admins do not, how to remove 'web' prefix?

Tags: 8, uri

I've setup Drupal 8 using https://www.lullabot.com/articles/goodbye-drush-make-hello-composer, but when I visit the site, all the links begin with web/ which means they break. If I remove web/ then they work. If I login, the links don't have web.

How would I remove web/? Where SHould I look in the source tree for a config file or otherwise to adjust this?

Comment: This could be a bug with the Composer approach to installing Drupal 8 as other folks who haven't used this don't get this issue, raised a ticket: https://www.drupal.org/node/2673164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed; the following steps for creating a drupal 8 site don't appear to have the issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2471553.

(Original issue posted on https://www.drupal.org/node/2673164.)